# GridFS: TypeError: grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Не могу получить файл из GridFS. Вот мой код:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const connect = mongoose.connection;

let gfs;

connect.once('open', () => {
  gfs = new Grid(connect.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('avatars');
});


router.get('/:filename', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename });
    const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename); // на этом моменте вылетает ошибка
    readStream.pipe(res);
  } catch (err) { 
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Not Found' });
  }
});
```

Файл находит, все хорошо, но при создании `createReadStream`, выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor
    at new GridReadStream (C:\Users\karrt\Documents\sneaky\fullstack-login-template\server\node_modules\gridfs-stream\lib\readstream.js:68:62)
    at Grid.createReadStream (C:\Users\karrt\Documents\sneaky\fullstack-login-template\server\node_modules\gridfs-stream\lib\index.js:53:10)
    at C:\Users\karrt\Documents\sneaky\fullstack-login-template\server\routes\avatar.routes.js:20:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Вот объект, который возвращает `gfs.files.findOne`:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6144c3a2323799ae2eefa93c"),
  length: 121123,
  chunkSize: 261120,
  uploadDate: 2021-09-17T16:34:42.865Z,
  filename: 'f9e9eb2d-fc2b-408c-a878-45eb6c6ae9e8-Screenshot-2021-09-14-061726.png',
  contentType: 'image/png'
}
```

`new ObjectId` возвращает мне `mongo`, но в конструкторе `Grid`, я указал что использую `mongo`...

Comment: Вообще, согласно документации, в `createReadStream` надо передавать не строку, а  объект с хотя бы одним из двух полей: `_id` и `filename`.

Comment: @Yaant пробовал уже, не помогло, тот синтаксис что в вопросе, это из туториала вообще…